# Return middleware in class

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, oop, middleware

I have a class with middleware function, which I want to return.
In middleware I want to use `this` statement, but now it is just undefined.
Class :

```
export class Validator {
    constructor(options: validatorOptions) {
        this.schema = options.schema
        this.validateRequest = options.validateRequest
        this.validateResponse = options.validateResponse
    }

    private validate(req, res, next) {
        console.log(this.schema) //undefined
    }

    public getValidator() {
        return this.validate
    }
}
```

Class declaration:

```
import {Validator} from './validator/validator'

export const validator = () => {
    const config = {
    schema,
    validateRequest: true,
    validateResponse: true
  }

  let v = new Validator(config)

  return v.getValidator()
}
```

Middleware usage:

```
import { validator } from './middleware'
app.use(validator())
```

How I can use `this` in returned middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validate` is a callback and should be bound to correct `this`, e.g. with class field:

```
private validate = (req, res, next) => { ... }
```